# I have two input data picker fields, in first field it should be like 01/01/2022 and in the second field should have current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

[image]

1. I have 2 input date fields
   1.1. One is for the start date and this should like:= 01/01/current-year(01/01/2022, the current year is 2022 so it should take this year and if the current year is 2023 then this should be like:= 01/01/2023).

1.2. the Second field should have the current date like:= 20/12/2022

I have attached the screenshot for your reference

```
enter code here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Date Picker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="start-date">Start Date</label>
    <input class="date-picker">
    <label for="end-date">End Date</label>
    <input class="date-picker">
</body>
</html>
```

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Any help with this requirement would be very grateful Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work? Please provide a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Karthik first i notice you should give an ID to the date picker elements in order to target them individiually.

Here's how html will be:

```
<label for="date-start">Start Date</label>
<input class="date-picker" id="date-start">
<label for="end-date">End Date</label>
<input class="date-picker" id="date-end">
```

And then javascript will be:

```
//current month and year
var yearNow = new Date().getFullYear();
var monthNow = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

//set the start date's field value to current year
document.getElementById('date-start').value = "01/01/" + yearNow;

//set the value of the end date field to current date
document.getElementById('date-end').value = monthNow + "/" + new Date().getDate() + "/" + yearNow;
```

I did `.getMonth() + 1` because getMonth() begins with 0.

---

***Update on the light of your comment on my answer***:

If I understand correctly, you need to add a checkbox which toggles the delete button viewability + you will need another button when clicked to show the Delete button:

**Additional HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">Show delete button</label>

<button id="delete-button" style="display:none">Delete</button>

<button id="select-all">Select All</button>
```

**Additional Javascript**:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var deleteButton = document.getElementById('delete-button');

//event listener to toggle the delete button viewability
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    deleteButton.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    deleteButton.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

//event listener for the "Select All" button which shows the delete  button:
document.getElementById('select-all').addEventListener('click', function() {
  deleteButton.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: it works now

I have one more requirement and I'll brief you on that where it needs to satisfy 2 conditions

Condition1: 

When the checkbox is checked I need to show a Delete Button, if not checked then I need to hide the button.

Condition 2:

There is a button called Select All even if I click on this button also I need to show the Delete Button else I need to hide the button

Currently, only one condition is getting satisfied now and I am not able to update the code or post a new question currently

currently, I need to satisfy both conditions with the same logic.

Comment: @KarthikReddy I updated my answer adding new code after my original answer. If this helped please don't forget to mark my answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: For the above requirement, we need to show 01/01/current-Year in the start date input field and in the end-date input field it should display the current day date. This condition is satisfied.

Comment: @KarthikReddy if it was useful to you can you please make it as answer?